# pointer and references

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a costume class called Region and I am using this bit of code to initialize the region variable how is that possible that at the end of this bit of code myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion is not nil and region is nil??? isn't myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion passed by reference to region???
I'm 100% sure that region is nil at the end of this piece of code.

```
Region *region=myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion;
if (!myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion) {
    myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion=[[Region alloc]init];
}
if (!region){ NSLog(@"region is nil");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It must be nil.
Because you change the object!

When doing `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion=[[Region alloc]init];` myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion points to a new object (a new address on the heap).

`*region` will **NOT** follow to the new address!

So `*region` still point to the `NULL` address.

But why you copy your pointer at line 1?
Why not always use `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion`. `*region` is a unlinked alias of `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion`

Just do at the end in your sample-dummy code and delete line 1:

```
if (!myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion){ NSLog(@"region is nil");
}
```

And by the way...

```
myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion=[[Region alloc]init];
```

looks like a memory leak (if your @property is set to retain).

Fix with:

```
myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion=[[[Region alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: I'm using ARC so I think it won't leak since my reference to myAppDelegate is a weak reference ARC will work just fine. Now I got it, how obvious...with my code region is point to nowhere all the time, it is never a point to myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion. Thank you very much... BTW I'm using the code I posted because I have to use myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion a couple of times so I'm calling it region instead just as a matter of convenience...

Answer (score 1):

`region` is a variable that contains a memory address.  `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion` is a  different variable that contains a memory address.

The first line of your code `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion` contains the memory address of nil which you then copy to `region`, i.e. `region` also contains the memory address of nil, **NOT** the memory address of `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion`.

Next you test if `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion` is nil, which it is, so you then set the content of `myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion` to  the memory address of a new `Region` instance.

region is a completely different variable that still contains the memory address of nil. So, finally when you are testing `region` it is still nil.

Comment: well it seems strange because i don't write region= nil i wrote region=myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion so region is now a pointer to the memory adress where myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion is stored if I change myAppDelegate.provisoryRegion what's stored in it's memory adress should change aswell so region should change too right? after all pointers work like that right?

Comment: I have updated my answer to hopefully make this a little clearer.